# MySQL Substring return empty value

Tags: mysql, substring

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(FieldName,0,20) FROM Table
```

I try on phpmyadmin and returned empty value.
How i use this function ?

Comment: Documentation for `SUBSTRING` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: would you pick the most upvoted answer as the answer ?

Answer (score 58):

The `SUBSTR` start index is `1` in mysql. So, you should change your code to:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FieldName,1,20) FROM TABLE;
```

Notice that `SUBSTR()` is a synonym for `SUBSTRING()` so they can be used interchangeably.

You should also checkout the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) for `SUBSTRING()`

Answer (score 16):

you must use `SELECT SUBSTRING(FieldName,1,20) FROM Table`, because from 0 is 0 :)

use 1

ups, someone wrote answer faster than I :)

Answer (score 11):

Try `SELECT SUBSTRING(FieldName,1,20) FROM Table`

Answer (score -1):

Use the syntax like my code below, I think it will be useful for your situation

```
SELECT  
SUBSTRING(course_designater,6,3) as 'Course number'                   
FROM    Courses
WHERE   course_designater LIKE 'Excel%' 
LIMIT 10
```